# Deep copy of a queue using assignment operator

Tags: c++, queue, operator-overloading, assignment-operator

I have troubles with the pointers using my assignment opperator, it doesn't make a new qeueu, instead the new array points to the old one. So when I delete in the new queue the values in my old queue changes.

First off all I can see that my copy constructor isn't called in my main for some unknown reason, the problem is probably related with that.

Some of my main code used to illustrate the problem:

```
aQueue.enqueue(10);
    aQueue.enqueue(20);

    Queue<int> cQueue = aQueue;             

    cout << "aQueue: "; aQueue.printQeueue(2, 0);
    cout << "cQueue: "; cQueue.printQeueue(3, 0);

    cQueue.dequeue();
    cout << "aQueue: "; aQueue.printQeueue(4, 1);
    cout << "cQueue: "; cQueue.printQeueue(5, 1);
    system("pause 4");
```

This is where the problems start, if I enqueue aQueue with 10 and 20 and then assign cQueue to aQueue, if I print aQueue the result is: 10 20. After that dequeue cQueue and print aQueue the result is: -179016023. If I print cQueue the result is: 20, as it should be.

The output: https://i.stack.imgur.com/0xRwC.jpg

Here follows the functions used direct or indirect:

```
template <typename T>
T Queue<T>::dequeue(){

    T temp = front();

    Node *old = fronten;
    fronten = fronten->next;

    delete old;

    return temp;

}


template <typename T>
Queue<T>::Queue(const T &rhs){

    Node *tempfront = rhs.fronten;

    while (tempfront.fronten!=rhs.back){
        enqueue(tempfront);
        tempfront = tempfront->next;


    }
}

template <typename T>
void Queue<T>::enqueue(const T& item){


    if (isEmpty()){
        back = fronten = new Node(item);
    }
    else
        back = back->next = new Node(item);
}

Node(const T &theElement, Node *n = nullptr): element(theElement), next(n) {};
```

Comment: please paste complete example that compiles

Comment: you don't have a copy ctor for Queue, yours template <typename T>
Queue<T>::Queue(const T &rhs) is constructor for Queue from the type it stores

Comment: @0d0a Now you lost me, but it sounds like it makes sence. So how should I define my copy ctor?

Comment: inside class : Queue::Queue(const Queue &rhs){//...}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have at the moment copy constructor for your Queue class (or you don't show it). Yours

```
template <typename T> Queue<T>::Queue(const T &rhs)
```

is constructor for Queue from the type it stores. You need something like:

```
template <class T>
class Queue
{
  public:
    Queue( const Queue &);                // copy ctor
    Queue& operator=( const Queue& q);   // assignment operator
  //...
};
```

Comment: Thank you! Been working so much it made me blind + my unknowledge ;D